# How to both type and have a drop down list in Ruby form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now, my drop down list is pulling values from a database file. However, there are too many values (150+ values) and searching them is a pain. Is there any way I can type the values as well?

While I type, the corresponding list values can be highlighted. This will help the user to find and select the value he/she requires.

Comment: Are you referring to having autocomplete functionality in your forms? Essentially having an autocomplete "select" (forgive my novice-level web-dev jargon)? If so, this is not really a RoR question per-se but is more of a javascript/UI question.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the Autocomplete function.

Comment: The reason I suggest re-tagging your question as javascript UI is that loading ALL 150+ values into the select via some json array in your form is trivial with RoR templating. Doing search on the client side with javascript autocomplete is preferable than ajax based search through the database, if you can keep the number of potential values to a reasonable size. You can still load them dynamically when the page is initially requested, but still autocomplete via javascript will be far more performant than ajax. Edit: elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best off using a js library like [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), which is easily integrated with rails if needed via [chosen-rails](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails), or just use it standalone!

No need to reinvent the wheel.